# Rails controller finder pattern to dry up an account filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller, dry

I have the code like below throughout my controllers. This is to filter the models for a particular account (for multitenancy). Is there an easy way to DRY this up? The `current_account_id` is a controller helper method which depends on the current user.

```
Job.with_account(current_account_id).active.......
Contact.with_account(current_account_id).active.......
```

Not sure if adding a helper method in Application controller is the best way.

Edit:
To clarify, I could use some code like below:

```
def job_with_current_account
  Job.with_account(current_account_id)
end
```

and then use this method everywhere in the controller e.g.

```
job_with_current_account.active.....
```

I was wondering if there was another, more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined the associations in both directions, and assuming you have a `current_account` helper, then you could use this instead:

```
current_account.jobs.active.....
current_account.contacts.active.....
```

It's a bit more concise, and you don't need to define the `with_account` scope in all of your models.

Comment: Wow, How did I miss this :) I actually have a current_account helper and all the relationships wired up. Thanks for helping me out :)